# Java return must not be null

Tags: java, null, return

I have the following code:

```
public abstract class Task<S extends AbstractScript>
    public S getScript() {
        return (S) Environment.getScript();
    }
}
```

Environment.getScript() returns the current AbstractScript

However, this AbstractScript might be null, but the S (which is an AbstractScript) returned at getScript() must not be null because it is used many times, therefore I don't want to null check it all the time.

I thought of null checking Environment.getScript(), but in the case of null I don't know what to return then.

Answer (score 1):

If it can't be null, but you don't know what to return instead, either:

Have the concrete implementation specify what its default should be:

```
public abstract class Task<S extends AbstractScript> {
    private final S deflt;
    protected Task(S deflt) {
        this.deflt = deflt;
    }

    public S getScript() {
        S s = (S)Environment.getScript();
        return s == null ? deflt : s;
    }
}
```

Or make the caller specify it:

```
public S getScript(S deflt) {
    S s = (S)Environment.getScript();
    return s == null ? deflt : s;
}
```